# Additional filed in Asp.net Membership sign up form

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating a simple asp.net website and i have used asp.membership to create a sing up and login features.

The main problem is that i also want users to be able to fill in their first and last names in the registrations.

At the moment, i have created another table to store other details like, first name, last name etc.

The sign up page currently has two form

1. The default asp.net sign up.
2. The other detail signup form to collect firstname.

Is it possible to merge this two forms into one, instead of making users fill 2 forms?

Comment: And what is on the sign up form? Are you using a CreateUserWizard Control? If yes, see [How to: Customize the ASP.NET CreateUserWizard Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178342(v=vs.100).aspx) (MSDN)

Answer (score 0):

Change the RegisterModel to hold the additional fields that you need, eg: firstName, lastname.

Then change the structure of the UserProfile table inside the database to hold the new fields.

Then use the following:

WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password, **new {FirstName = model.FirstName, LastName = model.LastName, all other properties});**